# Git core.editor on Mac OS X

Tags: git, text, macos, text-editor

How can I change the core.editor of Git to start a program such as Smultron?

All I can find are examples for terminal editors or TextMate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can open a file in Smultron with `open`

Example

```
git config core.editor "open -nW -a Smultron"
```

**EDIT**

Added the `-nW` parameters to have a new Smultron open and wait for it to close

Comment: This opens Smultron, though git quits early and returns:
"Aborting commit due to empty commit message."

Comment: Also --global would be a good idea otherwise you risk setting the editor just for the current project.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

And it appears Smultron has no more support in development. Hmf.

Comment: to open Komodo Edit type
    git config core.editor "open -nW -a 'Komodo Edit'"

Answer (score 0):

You only see terminal and TextMate examples because TextMate provides a terminal program to interface with it from the command line. If Smultron provides a similar program, you can use it the same way you use "mate." If not, then you can't make Smultron work with core.editor.

Comment: Do you know of any other text editors that have such a command?